# To Know the Number Of days between two dates using cursor

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table like this

```
SELECT V_EP_ID,V_START_DATE,V_END_DATE 
FROM PGATEINTRA.dbo.EMPLOYEE_VACATIONS 
ORDER BY V_EP_ID ASC
```

output of the above query is

```
V_EP_ID     V_START_DATE             V_END_DATE
------------------------------------------------------
28        2010-06-21 00:00:00     2010-06-21 00:00:00
103       2011-06-27 00:00:00     2011-06-27 00:00:00
103       2011-08-12 00:00:00     2011-08-12 00:00:00
104       2011-03-24 00:00:00     2011-03-24 00:00:00
104       2011-05-06 00:00:00     2011-05-06 00:00:00
104       2010-06-07 00:00:00     2010-06-08 00:00:00
104       2011-02-23 00:00:00     2011-02-25 00:00:00
...
```

I wrote the statement like this

```
SELECT * FROM PGATEINTRA.dbo.EMPLOYEE_VACATIONS 
WHERE V_START_DATE >='2010-06-21 00:00:00' 
   AND V_END_DATE <= '2010-06-21 00:00:00'
```

by passing v_start_date and v_end_date from `PGATEINTRA.dbo.EMPLOYEE_VACATIONS`

and I am getting the output as

```
V_ID  V_TYPE  V_EP_ID V_REASON      V_START_DATE         V_END_DATE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
3      c        28     Took leave   2010-06-21 00:00:00  2010-06-21 00:00:00
7      c       109     Took leave   2010-06-21 00:00:00  2010-06-21 00:00:00
```

I want output to get all the V_EP_ID FROM PGATEINTRA.dbo.EMPLOYEE_VACATIONS between V_START_DATE and V_END_DATE dynamically.

Comment: What do you mean by "DYNAMICALLY"? And what's with all the CAPS?

Comment: @Oded: Gob bless you. It's actually readable now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where cursors come into play here, but I think what you need is the `DATEDIFF` function:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, V_START_DATE, V_END_DATE) = 0
```